# What would be the repercussions of Megalodon never going extinct?

Tags: science-based, environment, alternate-history, ecology

A long time ago the 60ft long [Megalodon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megalodon) roamed the oceans, fast forward to 2.6 million years ago and they went extinct (and yes they definitely went extinct don't let the discovery channel fool you). But lets say that Megalodon never went extinct how might they affect the oceans ecology? As in would whales be as large as they are today?

Comment: I have the strong feeling this is too broad.

Comment: Have you looked up the evolution of whales before 3m years ago?

Comment: Small whales caused their extinction by cooperative hunting behaviour, Megalodon were one of their prey

Comment: @Kilisi lemme guess, that has the same citation source as the Borneo cyclone trees, right?

Comment: What factors were already different that would allow them to not be hunted to extinction by orcas? - we'd need to know this to answer - even then it's still opinion based. ([From review](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/close/67377)).

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi it wasn't discovery channel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you know that [Great White Sharks are *terrified* of orcas](https://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2019/04/great-white-sharks-flee-killer-whales/587563/)? like proper poop-their-ocean terrified. Tagged Great Whites who hear the click-click of a pod of hunting orcas dive to the deepest point they can and stay there for hours.

This is probably one of the reasons Megalodon went extinct*: eaten by the ancestors of orcas.

Baleen whales got to their current sizes right around the time Megalodon went extinct but there is no evidence that predation kept them small, you would expect the opposite: a race to giant size so that they become untouchable by sharks. Instead the race to gigantism seems to have been driven by changes in climate and ocean currents that meant more food was available.

So what would change if Megalodon hadn't gone extinct:

1. slightly fatter orcas
2. baby whales might try to grow even faster, mom-whales might be a bit more protective.
3. other large sea creatures like elephant seals will employ strategies that their smaller cousins employ today to dodge Megalodon.

But long story short: Megalodon didn't enjoy a ecological niche that isn't filled these days by modern large sharks or orcas so there is no reason to expect any widespread changes in the overall ecology  of the oceans, no matter how much a 10-metre shark speaks to the imagination.

* Megalodon extiction seems to have been one of those perfect storms: climate change, geological upheaval (Panama closing), astronomical events and the rise of a class of intelligent predators that know the trick to eating sharks.

Comment: There are evidence that Megalodon went extinct because of an astronomical event which hit large animals more than small one. And shark are terrified by orcas because they use to flip them upside down and suck their liver out while they are still alive, leaving then them to a slow death...

Comment: True, but Megalodon extiction seems to have been one of those perfect storms: climate change, geological upheaval (Panama closing), astronomical events and the rise of a class of intelligent predators that know the trick to eating sharks.

Comment: *This is probably how Megalodon went extinct: eaten by the ancestors of orcas.* Any evidence for this ?

Comment: I'd add 4: There would be one more entry on IUCN's list of endangered species, and one less on the extinct species.

Comment: This seems wrong. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megalodon) `A 2019 study reviewed newer evidence suggesting that competition from the modern great white shark may have also contributed to the extinction of megalodon, coupled with range fragmentation resulting in a gradual, asynchronous extinction`. [citation - open access](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6377595/) - read the abstract

Comment: Now please link the entire sub article: basically everything that could go wrong went wrong for megalodon. I've indicated as such in my answer.

Comment: Also: that bit of information has evolution backwards: a new species cannot displace a new one without changing circumstances first putting pressure on the old one